# Let $ABCD$ be a rectangle, $E$ midpoint of $DC$ and $G\in AC$ such that $BG\bot AC$. Let $F$ be a midpoint of $AG$. Prove $\angle BFE =\pi/2$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation

> Let $ABCD$ be a rectangle, $E$ midpoint of $\overline{DC}$ and $G$ point on $\overline{AC}$ such that $\vec{BG}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{AC}$. Also, let $F$ be  a midpoint of $\overline{AG}$. Prove that angle $\angle BFE =\pi/2$.

---

I found already 4 solution which I have posted here [Proving right angle using vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948977/proving-right-angle-using-vectors/2954066#2954066)

But now I'm interested in geometric transformation solution. I found this one also:

Spiral similarity $\mathcal{P}$ with center at $B$ that takes $A\mapsto D$ takes also $G\mapsto C$ and there for it takes midpoint $F$ of $AG$ to a midpoint of $CD$, that is $E$. Now this spiral similarity $\mathcal{P}$ induces new spiral similarity $\mathcal{P}'$ which takes $A\mapsto F$ and $D\mapsto E$  and also $B\mapsto B$, so we have $$\angle EFB = \angle DAB = 90^{\circ}$$

---

**Finaly, here is my question.** We notice also $$A\stackrel{\mathcal{P}}{\longmapsto}D \stackrel{\mathcal{S}}{\longmapsto}C \stackrel{\mathcal{P}^{-1}}{\longmapsto}G$$ where $\mathcal{S}$ is reflection across $E$. So transformation $$ \mathcal{T} = \mathcal{P}^{-1}\circ \mathcal{S} \circ \mathcal{P}$$
is reflection across $F$ that takes $A$ to $G$. Can we from here deduce that $\angle EFB = 90^{\circ}$?

Comment: As for the spiral similarity, I think $\mathcal{P}$ is enough, you do not need to induce a new one. $\mathcal{P}$ is composed of a homothety and a rotation with common center $B,$ thus the ratio is $\frac{BE}{BF}=\frac{BD}{BA},$ and the angle $\phi=\angle FBE =\angle ABD.$ Done.