# In a rhombus $ABCD$, prove that $IG\perp IP$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $ABCD$ be a rhombus with $\angle ADC=60^\circ$ (picture in attach file). The points $E$, $F$, $G$, and $H$ are midpoints on sides $AB$, $DA$, $CD$, and $BC$, respectively.  Let $J$ be the intersection of $FH$ and $AG$, and $I$ is midpoint of $FJ$. Prove that $IG \perp IP$.

[image: http://sv1.upsieutoc.com/2018/10/17/Capture1bad37ff2cfbfa35.png]

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: This can be done with just geometry (equilateral triangles, similar triangles, parallelograms, etc.) without vectors or algebraic equations. Is that what you want? Showing your own attempt would give us an idea of the style of proof you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ denote $AB=BC=CD=DA$.  Then, $\triangle AOF$ is equilateral with side length $\frac{a}{2}$.  That is, $OJ=FJ=\frac{a}{4}$, and $JI=\frac{a}{8}$.  Hence, $OI=OJ+JI=\frac{3a}{8}$.  Now, $BO=\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{2}$, so $PO=\frac{BO}{2}=\frac{\sqrt3a}{4}$.  Since $\angle POI=\angle POA+\angle AOF=90^\circ+60^\circ=150^\circ$, we have form the cosines' law that
$$PI^2=PO^2+OI^2-2\ PO\ OI\ \cos(\angle POI)=\frac{3a^2}{16}+\frac{9a^2}{64}-2\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}{a}}{4}\right)\left(\frac{3a}{8}\right)\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right).$$
So, $PI^2=\frac{39a^2}{64}$.

By Pythagoras, $\triangle IJG$ is a right triangle with $JG=\frac{AG}{2}=\frac{BO}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{4}$, so $$IG^2=IJ^2+JG^2=\left(\frac{a}{8}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{4}\right)^2=\frac{13a^2}{64}.$$
Similarly, $\triangle PHG$ is a right triangle with $PH=\frac{EH}{2}=\frac{AC}{4}=\frac{a}{4}$ and $HG=BO=\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{2}$, so that
$$PG^2=\left(\frac{a}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{2}\right)^2=\frac{13a^2}{16}.$$
Note that $$PI^2+IG^2=\frac{39a^2}{64}+\frac{13a^2}{64}=\frac{13a^2}{16}=PG^2.$$  By the converse to Pythagoras' theorem, $\angle PIG=90^\circ$.

---

Alternatively,let $FG$ meet $OD$ at $M$.  Since $M$ bisects $FG$ and $I$ bisects $FJ$, $IM$ is parallel to $JG$.  That is, $IM$ is perpendicular to $IH$, since $JG\perp OF$.  That is $\angle HIM=90^\circ=\angle HPM$.  That is $\square HPIM$ is cyclic.  This means 
$$\angle PIH=\angle PMH=\angle PGH.$$
Thus, $\square PIGH$ is also cyclic.  This implies
$$\angle PIG=180^\circ-\angle PHG=180^\circ-90^\circ=90^\circ.$$

Comment: OK. But not use Cosine Law

Comment: Whatever you don't want in a solution, you should put in your question, so that other users don't waste time writing a solution with what you don't want.  Plus, the calculation of $PI^2$ can be done without the law of cosines, using Pythagoras alone.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Let $O=(0,0)$, $A = (0,2)$ and $D = (2\sqrt{3},0)$.

Then $P = (-\sqrt{3},0)$, $H= (-\sqrt{3},-1)$, $G= (\sqrt{3},-1)$ and $F = (\sqrt{3},1)$.

Now the line $AG$ is $y= -\sqrt{3}x+2$ and the line $HF$ is $y= {\sqrt{3}\over 3}x$ and they meet at $$J=({\sqrt{3}\over 2},{1\over 2})\implies I = ({3\sqrt{3}\over 4},{3\over 4})$$

Now the slope of $PI$ is $k={\sqrt{3}\over 7}$ and the slope of $IG$ is $k' =-{7\over \sqrt{3}} $ so $k\cdot k'=-1$ and thus $\angle PIG = 90^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $HF||CD$ and $AG\bot CD$ we have that $AG\bot CD$. Now you can use this (observe only rectangular $EFGH$):

[Let $ABCD$ be a rectangle, $E$ midpoint of $DC$ and $G\in AC$ such that $BG\bot AC$. Let $F$ be a midpoint of $AG$. Prove $\angle BFE =\pi/2$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2956835/let-abcd-be-a-rectangle-e-midpoint-of-dc-and-g-in-ac-such-that-bg-bot)

or

[Proving right angle using vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948977/proving-right-angle-using-vectors)

Comment: Gọi $N$ là giao điểm $FG$ và $BD$, suy ra $N$ là trung điểm của $FG$.

Ta có $IN \parallel AG$, mà $AG \perp HF$ nên $IN \perp HF$. Do đó tam giác $IHN$ vuông tại $I$.

Gọi $K$ là giao điểm của $PG$ và $AC$, suy ra $K$ là trung điểm của $PG$.

Dễ dàng thấy được $GHPN$ là hình chữ nhật. Cho nên $K$ cũng là trung điểm của $HN$. Suy ra $KI=HK=KG = \dfrac{1}{2}PG$.

Vậy tam giác $PIG$ vuông tại $I$ hat $IP \perp IG$.

Comment: You should post that as an answer, not a comment!@CaoThànhThái